# Reasoning behind definition of $\operatorname{Proj} S$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a graded rings. We denote $S_{+}$ to be the ideal $\oplus_{d >0} S_d$.

We define the set $\operatorname{Proj} S$ to be the set of homogenous prime ideals $\frak{p}$, which do not contain $S_{+}$.

Is there a geometric significance as to why we don't want the homogenous prime ideals to contain $S_{+}$?

Comment: In the case where $S = k[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$, the ideal $S_+ = (x_0, \ldots, x_n)$ corresponds to the affine point $(0, \ldots, 0)$, which does not define a point in projective space.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more, recall that when we construct $\mathbb P^n$ from $k^{n+1}$ we do two things: delete the origin, and then take the quotient by the action of $k^*$. In scheme language, the former corresponds to the exclusion of $S_+$, while the latter corresponds to the presence of the word "homogeneous."